# Powershell v1.0 http request for Sharepoint data

Tags: http, powershell, sharepoint, request

I am on a pretty locked down environment where I only have powershell v1.0 available. I am trying to get internal Sharepoint data downloaded programmatically. I cannot do this with an ADODB Connection since the server does not have the appropriate driver for ADODB Connections.

Therefore, I want to make an HTTP Request for the data. However, so far my research indicates that powershell v1.0 does not have the ability to make such calls (although later versions do, they are not available to me).

I cannot use VBScript to accomplish this either as it is not available on the server.

Is there some way of making HTTP Requests using powershell v1.0, or is there another recommended way of getting this sharepoint data?

Answer (score 0):

```
$z = new-object system.net.webclient
$z.DownloadString('http://url')
```

No idea if this also works on v1.
Maybe you're better off using a curl build for Win32: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html